# How dumb is it to try to remount /proc as w?

Tags: samsung, linux, processes

I'm trying to run a little python code that check some files in my phone's /proc/pid

the thing is the program won't run properly because /proc is read only. Because I know proc has a special filesystem I want to know if there is a way to remount it as writeable without screwing up the system

Comment: Will adb shell cat /proc/whatever... adb shell first, might give you shell access to the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/proc` is a **pseudo**-filesystem supplied by the Linux kernel, so as to provide an interface to applications to learn about system runtime information (running processes, mounts, memory, etc.). Therefore there's no way to "mount" it as R/W since that's meaningless.

Some entry points (NOT files), however, are writable by themselves, for example most entries under `/proc/sys`. Do note that by writing to these entries you're not writing any files, but actually changing system parameters.

If your program is trying to write to another non-writable entry in `/proc`, it's probably malformed and should be tweaked. Again, `/proc` is not a real filesystem and everything inside are interfaces from the Linux kernel.

Read more (related or similar):

- [deleting a 'file' under /proc or /dev](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/14291/211239)
- [Which files are writable under /proc and why?](https://superuser.com/q/728402/688600)
- [(programming-related)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20595834/5958455)

Documentations (usually very long and complete and unsuitable for casual read):

- [`proc(5)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)